# Some help with sprite graphic

Tags: digital-forensics, binary-format

I am trying to get the sprites from a game from 1997 called Swing (US: Marble Master). The file is called [NORMAL.SET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnokKRE3G8URVdKWmdLSy1nM0E/view?usp=sharing) and contains a set of sprites. There is an executable named SHOWSET.EXE that displays the entire set after printing a number on each sprite.

There are also a file called [HINTERH.SWG](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwnokKRE3G8UdU5VTFVVMFkwME0&authuser=0) (SWG probably stands for SWING). I was able to figure out what this file type is using TiledGGD! It is raw data without headers, has the size 640x480, 16 bpp, big endian, (A)RGB. See Screenshot below.

[image: HINTERH.SWG opened in TiledGGD]

Using the same settings in TiledGGD I get a close approximation of the [NORMAL.SET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnokKRE3G8URVdKWmdLSy1nM0E/view?usp=sharing) image. Below you find the output from SHOWSET.EXE (left), aswell as the image how TiledGGD displays it (right).

[image: NORMAL.SET as displayd in game and in TiledGGD]

Using a screenshot of the SHOWSET.EXE output, I was able to get close to the codec (?correct term?) used for the pixel data in the NORMAL.SET. I do believe it is based on 16-bit ARGB1555, but still different. Below you see the image extracted from the screenshot. Let's call it screenshot-sprite.

[image: Sprite extracted from Screenshot]

Those are the first 192 bytes from NORMAL.SET

```
47 69 62 20 6D 69 72 20 27 6E 65 20 4B 75 67 65
6C 0A 00 1A 73 74 61 6E 64 61 72 64 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 9D 4F DD 32 00 00 00 00 68 27 01 00
14 00 01 0F 1E 00 1E 00 2C 03 00 00 03 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 03 00 0A 00 90 08 90 08 90 08 90 08 <1,2---
8F 08 8F 08 8E 08 6D 08 6C 04 6B 04 03 00 0A 00
03 00 08 00 90 08 91 08 91 08 91 08 91 08 91 08
90 08 90 08 8F 08 8E 08 6D 08 6C 04 6A 04 4A 04
03 00 08 00 03 00 06 00 91 08 91 08 B2 08 B2 08
B2 08 B2 08 B2 08 B2 08 B2 08 91 08 90 08 8F 08
8E 08 6D 08 6C 04 6B 04 49 04 48 04 03 00 06 00
03 00 05 00 90 08 B2 08 B2 08 B3 08 B3 0C B3 0C
```

Those are the first 192 bytes from the screenshot-sprite.

```
42 4D 50 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 00 00 00 38 00
00 00 1E 00 00 00 E2 FF FF FF 01 00 10 00 03 00
00 00 0A 07 00 00 3B 00 00 00 3B 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7C 00 00 E0 03 00 00 1F 00
00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 <1---
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 08 90 08 90 08 <2---
90 08 8F 08 8F 08 8E 08 6D 08 6C 04 6B 04 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 90 08 91 08 91 08 91 08 91 08 91 08 90 08
90 08 8F 08 8E 08 6D 08 6C 04 6A 04 4A 04 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

You can see the point where the data does probably begin (arrow 1), you see a similar hex string `90 08 90 08 90 08`.

You also see that the data in the screenshot-sprite probably begins with 10 byte-pairs (arrow 2). In the NORMAL.SET you find `0A 00`. Now I read about RLE and with some fantasy I could see a link between 10 byte-pairs and `0A 00` which I could translate into "ten times a black pixel".

I am still confused why I see two blue sprites in the NORMAL.SET, where in the screenshot there is only one blue sphere. But that is something I would care about at a later time.

**NOTE**
At this point I am quite sure that I am on the right track! I think RLE decompression is the only thing missing here, besides figuring out where the data starts and what the headers are supposed to mean. Maybe they aren't even of much use to me.

I am not sure, if I still have a question at the moment. If nobody disagrees, I would keep this here until I figured out the rest in the hopes that someday, to someone this will be helpful. I will update this as soon as I solved the riddle.

Until the, if you got a a solution for the RLE ready, don't be shy to post ;)

Comment: You'll have to give a lot more information before anyone can help you, starting with what file format this is. A screenshot from some kind of editor doesn't really help. What games used it? Where did you find it? File extension? Is it based on a known format (JPG,PNG,TGA)? Which editor(s) did you try? You get the idea...

Comment: Okay, I did. :)

Comment: Now this is a nicely formulated question! Hope someone can help you. ;)

Comment: You can try [Recource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Comment: The file extension has nothing to do with the file type in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is:

`14 00` are the first two bytes of a sprite. The raw bitmap data starts at offset 20, in this case with `03 00 0A 00`. The file is RLE encoded, `03 00` being the escape sequence and `0A 00` is telling me that 20 pixels with `00 00` (16 bpp) follow.

With this information I was able to reverse engineer the sprite group.